# Apache: error reading information on service httpd: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I compiled and installed Apache from source code on Amazon EC2 running Amazon Linux Distribute. After installation, I issue the following command:

```
$ sudo chkconfig --add httpd
```

I get the error:

```
error reading information on service httpd: No such file or directory
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Locate your Apache with locate command.Also check restarting the Apache and check if its show you in process-list also check httpd -S  command.

You can try this alternative:

Add to your script these lines:

```
#chkconfig: 345 80 20 
#description: example script
```

345 - levels 
80 - start priority 
20 - stop priority

These are example values, you can change them.

Add your script with command:
chkconfig --add